# Trace32: How get programmatically get maintenance key expiry month and year using t32apinet?

Tags: jtag, trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to get the maintenance key expiry month and year of lauterbach JTAG programmatically. I am using t32apinet for that. Is there a way to read the maintenance information using the api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the date of you maintenance key via the PRACTICE function `LICENSE.DATE(<idx>)`, where *idx* is the number of the attached serial number as it appears in the LICENSE.LIST window. Note, that one debug cable, plugged to your PowerDebug, can have up to 5 serial numbers and thus, also up to 5 maintenance key.

To get *idx* for the currently running PowerView executable use the PRACTICE function `LICENSE.getINDEX()`.

Putting both together you get: `LICENSE.DATE(LICENSE.getINDEX())`

You can test it by using the PRINT command in PowerView:

`PRINT LICENSE.DATE(LICENSE.getINDEX())`

You should get a string in the form of YYYY/MM e.g. 2020/07

To use a PRACTICE function via the remote API, use the API function T32_Cmd() together with the TRACE32 command EVAL and then get the result via the API function T32_EvalGetString().

E.g. in **C/C++**:

```
char mdate[4096];    
T32_Cmd("EVAL LICENSE.DATE(LICENSE.getINDEX())");
T32_EvalGetString(mdate);
printf("End Date: %s\n", mdate);
```

I am not skilled with **Visual Basic .NET** at all, but I guess there it should look like this:

```
Dim mdate As String   
T32.Cmd("EVAL LICENSE.DATE(LICENSE.getINDEX())");
T32.EvalGetString(mdate);
Log("End Date: " + mdate)
```

New versions of TRACE32 support also the slightly nicer API function T32_ExecuteFunction().